# XSLT 1.0 advanced calculations

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have been banging my head against a wall on this for a while. Our application processes a complex structure XML invoice from another system. The invoice contains rows of information which contain various counts. These counts may or may not contain a value. There is an overall document charge. We need to work out the unit charge. The formula would be the total cost divided by the total of the counts.

I have been working through the examples kindly provided by others regarding summing in XSLT1.0. I can use xsl:call-template to get the sum of the counts, but I don't know how to apply the result to the calculate the unit price.

Sample XML

```
<Document>
    <Row>
        <Count1>
            <Value>10</Value>
        </Count1>
        <Count2>
            <Value/>
        </Count2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Count1>
            <Value>5</Value>
        </Count1>
        <Count2>
            <Value>6</Value>
        </Count2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Count1>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </Count1>
        <Count2>
            <Value>3</Value>
        </Count2>
    </Row>
    <Charge>
        <Value>260</Value>
    </Charge>
</Document>
```

If I could see how to get the following XML output that would probably show me what I need.

```
<Document>
    <Row>
        <Total>10</Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Total>11</Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Total>15</Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
</Document>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Would love to help - but you need to post the XSL you've tried as well as clarify the objective.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `sum()` on the required Values, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/Document">
    <Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <Row>
        <Total>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(./*[Value&gt;0]/Value)"/>
        </Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the output:

```
<Document>
    <Row>
        <Total>10</Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Total>11</Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Total>5</Total>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Row>
</Document>
```